# How could humanoids evolve without having once been treedwellers?

Tags: creature-design, evolution, environment, humanoid

We look the way we do because our ancestors were once tree climbers of forests that started to recede and then they moved to the land and stood upright to carry food better. Could alien life evolve to look humanoid without this specific background? Let's say they have four limbs like us just for simplicity.

Comment: I believe the crux of the problem here is opposable thumb, not four limbs.

Answer (score 2):

[Humans potentially evolved to walk upright for multiple reasons with varying degrees of credibility- to use tools, to see farther and walk better](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/becoming-human-the-evolution-of-walking-upright-13837658/#:%7E:text=Walking%20upright%20on%20two%20legs,of%20the%20four-legged%20apes.&text=erectus%20(collectively%20called%20australopithecines)%20helped,in%20the%20evolution%20of%20humans.)

There are many quadrupeds. Humans are a quadruped who can see over Savannah grass. Tree climbing was just one reason they evolved four limbs.

Comment: Does anyone have any scenarios where quadraped evolves into biped not involving becoming treeclimbers

Comment: @Joe Smith [theropods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theropoda)